# numpy indexing into 4dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Im currently trying to modifie a 4d numpy array in a specific way and need to access the following
elements at any give position:

**shape : 2, 2, 3, 3**

[image]

it should also be possible to move the window into any direction
(up and down)

so in the end it should look like this

```
# original == array with shape(2, 2, 3, 3)
# change == array with shape(2,2,2,2)
# then i want to change the red windows values with the change array
original[: some kind of indexing :] += change
```

Comment: `original[:, :, :2, :2]`

Comment: What have you tried? What happened when you did it?

Comment: @MadPhysicist i actually just didnt really know how to properly index into it so all i did was basically just rubbish

Comment: @aminrd thanks! thats what i needed have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

With credit to @aminrd:

`original[:, :, :2, :2] += change`